# Scoping program local vs global variables in a python function within a jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I'm new to pyton and jupyter and spent a long time debugging a function. When my error was I simply didn't notice I missed changing a variable name within a function and it was accessing a global variable.

Am I able to prevent a python function in jupyter notebooks from access global variables so errors like this pop up more quickly?

Comment: You could avoid using global variables.

Answer (score 1):

Since the variable is global, it is normal that you were able to get its value. You can however try some stuff.

- First, you can try to avoid globally scoped variables, since those situations are prone to occur
- On other hand, you can use the `del` keyword after using your variables, deleting them ([here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_keyword_del.asp))
- Using Jupyter, you can also [shutdown/restart your kernel](https://jupyter-notebook-beginner-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute.html#:%7E:text=You%20can%20run%20the%20notebook,the%20menu%20Kernel%20%2D%3E%20Restart.), to clean your memory. You will then have to run again all the code you need, of course

Comment: @user2946746 if this solved your question, please close it and mark the answer